# How to get user country via Paypal API

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to get the country using their email? Or validate user's country.
In our system, the user submits their email and country. We need to check whether the country is correctly specified.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to force users to login paypal (you don't want to allow transactions by who doesn't have a paypal account)

See [SetExpressCheckout](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout) `SOLUTIONTYPE = Mark`

after the user completes the expresscheckout, in order to confirm it, you should check if its street address is confirmed and if it is of the country you require:

[GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetExpressCheckoutDetails)

```
PAYERSTATUS must be "verified"
COUNTRYCODE must be the country you require
```

if these two values are ok, you can confirm the payment with "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"

---

since you are new, if you like my answer don't forget to set it as "accepted"

Comment: if there are any methods to get to know the country of paypal user without transactions (checkouts) from his side?

Comment: yes, verifying its email https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_AddressVerify

Comment: It looks like this is what we need. But the problem is that we do not have values STREET and ZIP. And without them, it seems COUNTRYCODE is not returned in the response.

Comment: you can't do nothing in this case

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to verify customer's PP account country with out initiaing a transaction, is to implement "Login with PayPal" with your own customer login/register managenment.

It's based on the PayPal REST identity APIs, and will be much easier for you to get & manage customer account info (with user consent).

Here's the developemnt resource for your reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/